# Invalid value for field 'amount'. Payment from credit cannot exceed available credit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Freshbooks API in Codeigniter. When I make a payment from my side, I am getting the error "**Invalid value for field 'amount'. Payment from credit cannot exceed available credit.**"

Comment: Show us some code man.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given any code whatsoever but from the message these are my thoughts:

```
"Invalid value for field 'amount'
```

amount seems to accept only one type of input, maybe it only accepts an integer, a float or a string. Make sure that you are indeed using the exact same type of input as the expected input is.

Are you using commas or dots within the amount that shouldn't be there? Is the number too big?

```
"Payment from credit cannot exceed available credit."
```

I guess you're trying to charge someone but the user doesn't have enough money available on the credit card, just like the message says. Or you're trying to make the user pay to much money, that would actually conclude the two sentences together.

But really, show us some code if you want a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Codes starting with 
1 are general errors, 
2 are authentication errors,
3 are authorization errors,
4 are validation errors,
5 are processing errors.

I think above error code comes in series that starts with 5. 
Please contact freshbooks support. they have very good support team.
https://www.freshbooks.com/support
or write to
support@freshbooks.com

Answer (score 0):

Hannele from FreshBooks here.

I believe that error message indicates that you're trying to pay an invoice with existing credit for that client in FreshBooks, but that credit is not sufficient to cover the payment amount.

The way this happens is a *little* confusing but is available in our [documentation for payment.create](https://www.freshbooks.com/developers/docs/payments):

> This function can have one of three possible effects depending on the presence of invoice_id and client_id:
>
> - If you specify an invoice_id only, the payment will be recorded as an invoice payment.
> - If you specify a client_id only, the payment will be recorded as a client credit.
> - If you specify both an invoice_id and client_id, the payment will be recorded as an invoice payment, and the amount will be subtracted from the client’s credit.

I'm just guessing based on the error message, but it looks like you would like to create a regular payment. So, specify just the invoice id, and not the client id.

If you would like to make a credit, then specify just the client id.

Hope that helps!